# How to add a menu page for options in wordpress for user that has the role of vendor?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles, capabilities, add-menu-page

I want to add new options page **ONLY for those users whose role is vendor**. How can I do that? This is my current code.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'business_settings_menu');

function business_settings_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Business Settings', 'Business Settings', 'administrator', 'business_settings', 'business_settings_page', 'dashicons-arrow-right-alt', '31.6');
    add_action('admin_init', 'business_settings');
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that when administrator logins, he can see this page. But when I login from my vendor account, I am unable to see this link. Can anyone guide me? I have `woocommerce` installed on my wordpress.

Comment: Can you please update your question with a code which you used to register 'Vendor' user role? That will provide sufficient details to provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to [`add_menu_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) is `$capability`.

```
add_menu_page( 
  $page_title, 
  $menu_title, 
  $capability, 
  $menu_slug, 
  $function, 
  $icon_url, 
  $position 
);
```

That governs who can see the page. You've registered yours as "administrator", which is a [user role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). Presumably your vendors are not of that role. To fix this, you will need to change that argument to a capability (preferably not a role) that your vendors have. You can [create custom capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) for this, which is probably what I'd do.

Comment: When I add a new user, There is a dropdown for roles. In that role, I have chose **vendor**. What should I write in capability so that the settings menu appear only when vendors login through their admin panel?

Comment: Depends on how you've registered the role. You can probably use the role name but that is known to be a bit buggy (wish that would be fixed). That is why I suggest you add a specific capabability.